# Crossing borders for a couple hours inside the Schengen area with a group of children

Tags: schengen, children, austria, eu-citizens, czech-republic

I'm a scoutmaster in the Czech Republic and we would like to visit Austria for couple hours with my scout troop (aged 12-16, we're all Czech citizens). Are there any special rules about such situations when I (not the parent) travel with children to another Schengen country for such a short time? What documents do I need from each of the children?

Comment: I think all countries require that the children have identity papers, and some require a separate authorization, but the rules for this are not uniform across Schengen. I don't know about the rules for Austria and the Czech Republic. In practice, it's likely that nobody will check, but obviously you'd want to make sure that everybody has the right papers just in case.

Comment: Are you and your scouts from EU or from 3rd country?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need a parent's authorization even in situations where you don't leave the country.

Comment: @JonathanReez Parents' authorization is not a problem, problem is that not all <15 children have ID/passport.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [official EU website](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/index_en.htm):

> In addition to their own valid passport or ID card, all children
>   travelling:
>
> alone; or with adults who are not their legal guardian; or with only
>   one parent may need an extra (official) document signed by their
>   parents, second parent or legal guardian(s) authorising them to
>   travel.
>
> You should first consult the local embassy of the country the children
>   are travelling to for information on which, if any, other documents
>   they need to make the trip.

Which means that the children would need their own ID Card (Obcansky prukaz) as well as an official authorization from their parents.

Comment: Thanks, I certainly wasn't aware that I need parents' permission for this. Don't you know please if "minors" means `<15yo` or `<18yo`?

Comment: I think it's best if you contact the Austrian embassy.